# Responsive issue in constraint layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, responsive-design

My layout has a constraint layout as a root element. 
There is the issue of responsiveness in the **forgot password section** as a view.
Following is the code snippet that has an error in responsive.
Please Suggest me.
[image][image: Responsive Design]

This chunk of code is for password edit text view and forgot password view

//TextInputLayout for password visibility

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInput"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_80sdp"
    android:background="@drawable/shapelogin"
    app:hintEnabled="false"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/backgroundImage"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.573"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">
      
 //edit textfield  
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/epassword"
                style="@style/activity_font_edit_field_password"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/shapelogin"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_icon_password"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_start_padding"
                android:singleLine="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/backgroundImage"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.573" />
    
    
   

         </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
            
//forgot password imageview
       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_68sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/shapelogin"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textInput"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.91"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textInput"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.573" />
       



 //forgot text inside button
       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewForget"
        style="@style/activity_font_forgot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/password_forgot"
        android:background="@drawable/shapelogin"
        android:textColor="@color/linkColor"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textInput"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.891"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textInput"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.516" />
```

Comment: Share us whole xml code.@Hubby Tiwari

Comment: Which of these behaviour do you want?

Comment: @androidLearner I have shared the codeshare link here:: https://codeshare.io/8pyBoE

Comment: @Praveen I want the same height of  "Forgot password view" with "Password Edit text view".That means fit equally in height and left side.

Comment: In your layout most of the view has parent as constraint .if you want responsive layout you need to set siblings as constraint . for instance view that you want below another view should has constraint to top view not parent.so you need to rewrite your whole layout.@HubbyTiwari

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the layout height for your view `textViewForget`.

Instead of `wrap_content` make it `0dp` which will be treated as `MATCH_CONSTRAINT` that indicates the view should fill up all available space specified wrt top and bottom constraints (in this case your edit text view)

Also in your layout there seems to be arbitrary horizontal/vertical bias set, you might want to check for correctness in the layout preview with different screen sizes.

Please refer to the documentation for more info - https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#DimensionConstraints